# Question about projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $B^T AB$ is not a projection, then either $B$ isn't orthogonal, or $A$ isn't a projection.

I understand that orthogonal $B$ and projection $A$ help transform the following: $B^T ABB^T AB = B^T AAB = B^T AB$. But I need to prove negation. How to deal with it?

Comment: Do you know what a contraposition is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove the contrapositive.

**Edit:** Your initial statement is: $$B^TAB\neq (B^TAB)^2\implies (BB^T\neq I\lor A^2\neq A.)$$ And you should know that $(BB^T\neq I\lor A^2\neq A)\iff \neg(BB^T=I\land A^2=A)$.

Comment: I know that  $A\Rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$. But here, I have a complicated B, involving "either or". I don't know how to transform it

Comment: So, in words, if both A,B are not what I want them to be, then $B^T AB$ is projection. Right? Sounds strange

Comment: @vovan No, that's the opposite direction of what you're trying to prove. Can you find the contrapositive of your statement?

Comment: Or I shouldn't make contrapositive for $B^T AB \neq (B^T AB)^2$, i.e. $B^T AB = (B^T AB)^2$

Comment: $\neg(BB^T=I\land A^2=A) \Rightarrow B^T AB \neq (B^T AB)^2$.

Comment: @vovan Wrong, that's not the contrapositive. That's the opposite direction of the implication. Let $P$ be the statement $B^TAB= (B^TAB)^2$ and let $Q$ be statement $BB^T=I\land A^2=A$. Then what you want to prove is: $\neg P\implies \neg Q$, right? What is the contrapositive of $\neg P\implies \neg Q$?

Comment: I'm confused. As I wrote, I would take negation from both P,Q and reverse them, so $Q \Rightarrow P$.

Comment: @vovan That's right. But that's not what you wrote in your previous comment.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted iff sign in the last line of your answer. So, I should prove $(BB^T=I\land A^2=A) \Rightarrow B^T AB = (B^T AB)^2$. But I've already done that in the post :)

Comment: @vovan Yes, you have. And you're done.

Comment: thank you for help and being patient :)

Comment: @vovan No problem.

Comment: @GitGud: Sorry if I made any bad feelings there. So accept this one instead. $+^{+^{+}}$

Comment: @BabakS. You didn't do anything wrong. Thanks.